# Почему при применении фильтра svg фигуры съезжают и как это исправить?

Tags: svg

Я хочу сделать исключение фигур. Вот здесь я использую фильтр:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter1">
      <feImage href="#1" result="1"/>
      <feImage href="#2" result="2"/>
      <feComposite in="1" in2="2" operator="xor"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g filter="url(#myFilter1)">
    <circle id="2" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    <g id="1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="#ccc"/>
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

А вот здесь без фильтра:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g>
    <circle id="2" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    <g id="1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="#ccc"/>
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Как видно, при применении фильтра, фигуры съезжают. Почему это происходит и как исправить?

Методом тыка я обнаружил, что дело в `feImage`. А также смещение зависит от количества элементов и от их расположения. Сделал, чтобы позиция элементов изменялась от положения мыши:

```js
const value = (max = 100000000, min = 0) => Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const createCircle = (size) => {
  const r = value(10, 3);
  const cx = value(size - r - 10, r + 10);
  const cy = value(size - r - 10, r + 10);
  return {
    r,
    cx,
    cy
  }
};

const createCircles = (counts, size) => Array(counts).fill().map(() => createCircle(size));


class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        position: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
        }
      };

      this.size = 300;

      this.circlesData = createCircles(100, this.size);

      const getCoords = (c, i) => c + (this.state.position.x * 0.002 * c * (i % 2 ? 1 : -1));

      this.circles = () => this.circlesData.map((item, i) => <circle key = {`circles_12dew1_${i}`} cx={getCoords(item.cx, i)} cy={getCoords(item.cy, i)} r={item.r}/>);

    }

    onMouseMove = e => {
      const position = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY,
      };
      this.setState({position});
    }

    render() {
      return (
      <div className = "App" >
        <svg onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove} ref = {elem => this.svg = elem} xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width = {this.size} height = {this.size} viewBox={`0 0 ${this.size} ${this.size}`}>
          
          <defs>
            <filter id="myFilter1">
             <feImage href="#1" result="1"/>
             <feImage href="#2" result="2"/>
             <feComposite in ="1" in2="2" operator="xor"/>
            </filter>
 
          </defs>

          <g id = "3" filter = "url(#myFilter1)" >
            <circle id = "2" cx={this.size / 2 + 100} cy={this.size / 2 + 100} r={this.size / 3}/>
            <g id="1"> {this.circles()} </g> 
          </g>
        </svg> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Большой круг должен стоять на месте, а он движется.

Какой фильтр использовать для svg фигур?? Или как исправить, без костылей, `feImage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все оказалось довольно просто. `<feImage>` по умолчанию имеет следующие атрибуты:

```
x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%"
```

И именно из-за этого и смещается изображение.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#filters-feImageElement

Нужно выставить следующие атрибуты и все будет работать корректно:

```
x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter1">
      <feImage href="#1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" result="1"/>
      <feImage href="#2" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" result="2"/>
      <feComposite in="1" in2="2" operator="xor"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g filter="url(#myFilter1)">
    <circle id="2" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    <g id="1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="#ccc"/>
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```js
const value = (max = 100000000, min = 0) => Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const createCircle = (size) => {
  const r = value(10, 3);
  const cx = value(size - r - 10, r + 10);
  const cy = value(size - r - 10, r + 10);
  return {
    r,
    cx,
    cy
  }
};

const createCircles = (counts, size) => Array(counts).fill().map(() => createCircle(size));


class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        position: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
        }
      };

      this.size = 300;

      this.circlesData = createCircles(100, this.size);

      const getCoords = (c, i) => c + (this.state.position.x * 0.002 * c * (i % 2 ? 1 : -1));

      this.circles = () => this.circlesData.map((item, i) => <circle key = {`circles_12dew1_${i}`} cx={getCoords(item.cx, i)} cy={getCoords(item.cy, i)} r={item.r}/>);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.svg.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        const position = {
          x: e.pageX,
          y: e.pageY,
        };
        this.setState({position})
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
      <div className = "App" >
        <svg ref = {elem => this.svg = elem} xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width = {this.size} height = {this.size} viewBox={`0 0 ${this.size} ${this.size}`}>
          
          <defs>
            <filter id="myFilter1">
             <feImage x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  href="#1" result="1"/>
             <feImage x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  href="#2" result="2"/>
             <feComposite in ="1" in2="2" operator="xor"/>
            </filter>

            <filter id="myFilter2">
              <feImage x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  href="#4" result="1"/>
              <feImage x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  href="#3" result="2"/>
              <feComposite in="1" operator="in"/>
            </filter> 
          </defs>

          <g id = "3" filter = "url(#myFilter1)" >
            <circle id = "2" cx={this.size / 2 + 100} cy={this.size / 2 + 100} r={this.size / 3}/>
            <g id="1"> {this.circles()} </g> 
          </g>
        </svg> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Спасибо большое [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)

[Этот же вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002103/how-to-exclude-shapes-in-svg-or-canvas)

Comment: не работает firefox

Comment: Да, к сожалению, firefox не поддерживает данные фильтры. Обидно! Даже в IE11 работает корректно!

Comment: @Igor отличный вопрос и ответ! (++)